# How do I retrieve a list of base class objects without joins using NHibernate ICriteria?

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

Let's say I have a base class called Pet and two subclasses Cat and Dog that inherit Pet.

I simply map these to three tables Pet, Cat and Dog, where the Pet table contains the base class properties and the Cat and Dog tables contain a foreign key to the Pet table and any additional properties specific to a cat or dog. A joined subclass strategy.

Now, using NHibernate and ICriteria, how can I get a list of all the different pets as Pet objects, **not Cat or Dog objects - just plain Pet objects**, without making any joins to the other tables? I am only interested in the information contained in Pet.

Comment: I had to resort to native SQL to get this one to work. But that gives me a lot of code to build the query string dynamically, based on e.g. filters. There has to be a way to do this with just ICriteria. Ayende must have thought about that, right?

Comment: I'm curious if this can be done with HQL -- this article (http://randomcode.net.nz/2008/09/19/restricting-types-returned-from-a-polymorphic-query/) indicates it can but your case is different since you are restricting the results to a base class type.

Answer (score 1):

I just did something similar and found this [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/10/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-inheritance.aspx) by Ayende extremely helpful! I went with a joined-subclass approach and it nicely supports querying the base class.

However, to find "only pets" without joining I think you'd need the table-per-class hierarchy approach. Or, you could use the table-per-subclass and just do left joins on the subclasses and restrict it to rows that had no matches on any of the left joins.

Comment: That was a great post by Ayende. I found the unioned subclass strategy to be interesting, I'll have to look into that. I wonder what the performance hit would be if I wanted the top 10 results from like 7 unioned tables though...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, selecting 'as pet' would I think bring back all object (not just the pets that are not subclassed).  I don't know of a clean way of doing it, but then I'm not an NH expert.

**Maybe you could query the discriminator column in the parent table directly?**  Although perhaps you would have to resport to a custom SQL query rather than HQL or ICriteria.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok:

I created a view that made selected all columns on the *Pet* table. I then created a simple DTO class that I mapped to the view. After that, ICriteria can be used.

Not the prettiest or cleanest solution perhaps, but certainly easier to work with than dynamic query strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with the Criteria API. However, you can do it with HQL:

```
var hql = @"from Pet p where p.class = Pet";
```

Comment: This would join all over the place. It would not return cats or dogs as pets, only the ones that are nothing more than pets. Perhaps I was a bit unclear about that I want all pets of all kinds, but only the information that the Pet class contains.

Comment: That's what you asked for: "not Cat or Dog objects - just plain Pet objects" and I wouldn't expect this to produce any joins. If what you really want is Cat or Dog objects "coerced" into Pet objects then you'll have to do it yourself. That's a non-object oriented approach and I wouldn't expect (or want) NH to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a new map for "PetsOnly" and and remove your discriminator and other non required fields? I think Kristoffer above aluded to the same thing; should still give you full insert update and delete select support. The pet is only a `Pet`...

Answer (score 0):

good enough for many situations: project the properties into the object itself.

**USE WITH CARE BECAUSE THE OBJECT IS BROKEN IN THE SENSE THAT IT HAS NOT THE CORRECT TYPE**

```
var propsToSelect = Projections.ProjectionList();
foreach (var prop in sessionfactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(Pet)).PropertyNames)
{
    propsToSelect.Add(Projections.Property(prop.Name), prop.Name);
}
var results = session.CreateCriteria<Pet>()
    .SetProjection(propsToSelect)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Pet>())
    .List<Pet>();
```